# "I went to the cinema after eating my dinner" - is "after" a preposition or subordinating conjunction?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, conjunctions, style-manuals

English schools are introducing some assessment tests for all children.  Some people are unhappy with this.  A politician was interviewed on the radio about it, and was asked one of the questions. (This is for 10 and 11 year old children).

> "I went to the cinema after eating my dinner" - is "after" a preposition or subordinating conjunction?

There is a clip here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p03syxdv

**Is "after" in the quoted sentence a subordinating conjuction, or a preposition?**

Comment: They will doubtless want the answer 'preposition'. The fact that the ing-form _eating_ here is near the verbal extreme (compare 'I went to the cinema still drinking my coffee' and  'I went to the cinema after I had eaten my dinner') is usually not considered enough to discount prepositional usage of _after_. I understand more and more why John Lawler believes that word-classification is often futile.

Answer (score 1):

"**after**" in the subject sentence is a **preposition**.

"**after** ***eating my dinner***" is a prepositional phrase with "eating my dinner" as the objective.

---

Had the sentence been constructed as "I went to the cinema **after *I ate dinner***." the word **after** would have functioned as a subordinating conjunction.

"**after** ***I ate dinner***" is a subordinate clause (with subject and verb) and **after** as the subordinating conjunction.